# Parcel - Unexpected token name «_28», expected punc «,»

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bundling-and-minification, parceljs

I am using [Color](https://npmjs.com/package/color) JavaScript Library in my Code, And I Am Using [Parcel JS](https://parceljs.org/) for bundling my Code.

When I Am Running Parcel JS For Development Using This Command -

- `parcel public/index.html`

Everything Works Fine.

But When I Build My Code For Production Using This Command -

- `parcel build public/index.html --public-url ./ --target browser`

I Get This Error -

```sh
> neusprite@0.0.1 build
> parcel build public/index.html --public-url ./ --target browser

  /home/aditya/Documents/Codes/NeuSprite/node_modules/color/index.js: Unexpected token name «_28», expected punc «,»
    at Z.get (/home/aditya/Documents/Codes/NeuSprite/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:525)
    at Object.errorToJson (/home/aditya/Documents/Codes/NeuSprite/node_modules/@parcel/utils/src/errorUtils.js:9:20)
    at Pipeline.process (/home/aditya/Documents/Codes/NeuSprite/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Pipeline.js:29:26)
    at async Object.run (/home/aditya/Documents/Codes/NeuSprite/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/worker.js:15:12)
    at async Child.handleRequest (/home/aditya/Documents/Codes/NeuSprite/node_modules/@parcel/workers/src/child.js:60:26)
```

One thing to note is that when i use this following option `--no-minify` like this `parcel build public/index.html --public-url ./ --target browser --no-minify` it Just Works Fine.

On StackoverFlow I Found this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42634780/14516016)

> UglifyJs does not support ES6. The error is very likely the method shorthand syntax.

But On The [Parcel JS Documentation](https://parceljs.org/features/production/) They Have Mentioned that they Use [Terser](https://github.com/terser/terser)

> Parcel uses terser to minify JavaScript, cssnano for CSS, htmlnano for HTML, and svgo for SVG. If needed, you can configure these tools using a .terserrc, .cssnanorc, .htmlnanorc, or svgo.config.json config file. See the docs for JavaScript, CSS, HTML, and SVG for more details.

And Terser Clearly Mentions It is Suitable For ES6+ On Their GitHub Page.

> A JavaScript parser and mangler/compressor toolkit for ES6+.

Then Why I Am I getting This Error?

Comment: What part of your code causes this?

Comment: in developer tools it's the `color` js library i am using